# How to access component in typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a basic Angular Application looking like this:

```
app.component.html:

<head>
  <title> My Home Page </title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test Umgebung</h1>

<div>
  <label>Firstname</label>
  <input placeholder="Firstname"/>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Lastname</label>
  <input placeholder="Lastname"/>
</div>

<div id="cloneContainer">

</div>

<button (click)="cloneUpper()">+ Add more Users</button>

</body>


</html>
```

As you can see, I type in Users and when I click on the "Add more Users" button, the following method should be executed:

```
app.component.ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CloneComponentComponent } from './clone-component/clone-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'UserManager';

  cloneUpper(){
    console.log("Cloned!");
    var cln = new CloneComponentComponent();    
    var container = document.getElementById('cloneContainer');
    container?.append(cln.toString());
  }
}
```

The clone component just contains a input for firstname and lastname in order to add more users. Now, when I click the button, it just appends [object Object] to the "cloneContainer". What could be the mistake?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

First suggest relationships, such as parent-child relationships, ways to get child components via viewChild, or public parameters via service

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you don't need to get from DOM via `getElementById` anything. Just add [conditional rendering](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```html
<div id="cloneContainer">
  <!-- CloneComponentComponent selector -->
  <clone-component *ngIf="showClone"></clone-component> 
</div>
```

Now your clone is visible only when `showClone = true`, so let's add this varable into your `AppComponent` and change `cloneUpper` method:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'UserManager';
  showClone = false;

  cloneUpper(){
    this.showClone = true;
  }
}
```

In case you need to handle array of clild components (push new ones) you can do the same trick with array:

```html
<div id="cloneContainer">
  <!-- CloneComponentComponent selector -->
  <clone-component *ngFor="let clone of clones"></clone-component> 
</div>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'UserManager';
  clones = [];

  cloneUpper(){
    this.clones.push(true); // whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: this.clones.push(true) -> this shows an error

Comment: @FlorianHaberfellner update your snipper or share error message, because this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at this the wrong way, please go through https://angular.io/tutorial to learn the basics of angular. That being said, this is the perfect use case for a child component. The child component is a dumb component in this case, just taking in an  object. I created an array of users, passing one user in initially and when clicking button pushing more users into the array. The dumb component only displays these form fields. I attached `ngModel` to bind the values as well. You will learn all this in the tutorial, but to get you started... create an interface:

```ts
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Great, now we have a model, as we are using TypeScript, it can now help us in the IDE if we are doing something silly. Next, create an array, push an initial object to it:

```ts
users = [{ firstName: '', lastName: ''}] as User[];
```

Cool... now the function that will be called when we want to add more users:

```ts
addUser() {
  this.users.push({ firstName: '', lastName: ''})
}
```

And over to the child, we'll just call it `DumbComponent`. We declare [`@Input()`](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) for the child, as we will be feeding the user object to it:

```ts
@Input() user: User;
```

Ok, and the child template will just have two fields, the firstname and lastname, bound with [**`ngModel`**](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngModel):

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name"/>
```

Then we in parent iterate the `users` array and display a child component which is fed the current user in iteration:

```html
<dumb-component *ngFor="let user of users" [user]="user"></dumb-component>
```

and the button of course:

```html
<button (click)="addUser()">Add user</button>
```

That's it! Read through the tutorial linked on top, you will learn the basics of angular right there! :)